# Dnn 9 - Set admin language to English and site language to Dutch

Tags: dotnetnuke-9

I'm working on a site which will have Dutch as its primary language, but I'd like the admin side of things to still be in English.

I've installed the site configuring it to use Dutch as the default language which means admin is also in Dutch.
I then go to Site Settings and activate En-Us but this automatically adds site aliases for both Dutch and English adding /nl-nl/ or /en-us/ to the URL.

All I want is for my site to be in Dutch, but for the Admin side of things to remain in English. Is this possible?

I've also tried enabling "Users May Choose interface Language" thinking that this applies purely to content editors, but this requires that both languages be installed which means we already have the issue where the site is in two languages with the language selector (flags) showing up.

I've set the admin user's preferred locale to English, but this makes no difference to the fact that the site is still in both Dutch and English.

I've changed the default Site alias removing the /nl-nl from the primary site alias which does work, but the user still has the option of selecting a language from persona bar (flags).

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 language activated (Dutch) and you have the admin users preferred locale set on English, you have what you're looking for.

Cheers
Tycho